# Is it possible to save an array of JSON objects in MySQL using Spring JPA + Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a table called `employee` with one of the attributes being list of skills. I would like to save this list of skills as an array in same table as `employee`

I do not want to(cannot even if I wanted to) create a separate table to save these objects/skills.

I am sharing the relevant piece of the code:

Employee.java

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    
    private int id;

    private List<Skill> skills = new ArrayList<>();

    //Getter and Setter
}
```

Skill.java

```
@Entity
public class Skill {
    
    private String name;

    private String category;

    //Getter and Setter

}
```

I tried looking for some answers posted by others and I found examples for saving JSON object with MySQL and Spring JPA but not a JSON Array (With Spring JPA)

[Link 1](https://prateek-ashtikar512.medium.com/how-to-handle-json-in-mysql-4adaeeb1d42f)

[Link 2](https://vladmihalcea.com/sql-server-json-hibernate/)

I also found an example where array of JSON objects is mapped to Java entity but it only works with Postgres

[Link 3](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-json-collections-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)

I would really appreciate some help with this and please let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly it's possible to store JSON data in MySQL using Spring JPA and Hibernate. However, MySQL itself doesn't have a native JSON data type **`before version 5.7`**, so you might need to use a string column to store JSON data.

For save an array of JSON objects using Spring JPA and Hibernate,
you can refere bellow steps,

1.First you should defined the Enity class like this,

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private String skills; //you can store JSON strings 

    // keep getters and setters in here
}
```

2.And then Serialize/Deserialize JSON:

You want to manually serialize/deserialize the `List<Skill>` to/from JSON when saving/retrieving data from the database. You can use libraries like Jackson for this purpose.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonUtil {

    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static String convertObjectToJson(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }

    public static <T> T convertJsonToObject(String jsonString, Class<T> valueType) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, valueType);
    }

    // Other utility methods if needed
}
```

3.Save and retrive skils as JSON,

When you saving the Employee object you shpuld before convert the List to JSON string using the utility method, and when retrieving, convert the JSON string back to the List.

example,

```
/ Saving an Employee with Skills
List<Skill> skillsList = // Your list of skills
String skillsJson = JsonUtil.convertObjectToJson(skillsList);
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setSkills(skillsJson);
employeeRepository.save(employee);

// Retrieving employee Skills
Employee retrievedEmployee = employeeRepository.findById(employee.getId()).orElse(null);
if (retrievedEmployee != null) {
    String retrievedSkillsJson = retrievedEmployee.getSkills();
    List<Skill> retrievedSkillsList = JsonUtil.convertJsonToObject(retrievedSkillsJson, new TypeReference<List<Skill>>() {});
    // Use retrievedSkillsList as your neededs
}
```

But remeber that stroing JSON as a string has limitation.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a solution where it would automatically map the Array of objects to the column and vice-versa but this is also amazing. I can introduce a DTO to do some transformation between client (REST request) and DB. I will try this solution and keep you posted.  Thank you @DhanushahDiilshan